# Creating a % change column in Google Sheets pivot table - aka pivot values calculated from pivot values

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

My raw data is numeric values against day/date. I have then setup a pivot table to show average value for each year:

[image]

[image]

I want to add a column of % change between the years; it looks like Excel has a built in for this but not Sheets unfortunately.

Is it possible to do this calculation as part of the pivot table?

I've been trying to use a Calculated Field and use a formula that works in a standard sheet/table. But the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions don't seem to update and always refer to the first row/column in the pivot table.

E.g. in this `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1))` every cell refers to the first row; column works ok though as that doesn't change between cells.

*The full formula I'm trying to use is: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1))/INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1))*100`*

I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not use a pivot table in this case? I have a formula that works on a normal sheet view for your issue but it does not work when applied to a calculated field in a pivot table. I recommend adding an extra column to your pivot table and then adding a formula.